# Making HTML text dofollow link with JavaScript is effective for SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, javascript

I wanted to replace match text to html link in content area in each post on WordPress site.

I implemented that by JavaScript as follows.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var selector = `article p` ;

  for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll( selector ).length; i++){
    if ( document.querySelectorAll( selector )[i].innerText.match(/(vpn|VPN)/) !== null ){
      var term = document.querySelectorAll( selector )[i].innerText.match(/(vpn|VPN)/)[1]
      document.querySelectorAll( selector )[i].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll( selector )[i].innerHTML.replace( term ,`<a href="https://yuis-programming.com/vpn">${term}</a>`)
      break
    }
  }

});
```

As you can see the one replace plain HTML text with `p` tag for hyperlink with dofollow.

So, this is my question. Does such JavaScript work correctly for SEO?

Comment: Do you care much about minor search engines other than Google (like Bing)?

Comment: A little, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Google can't see some JavaScript links, so you need to be careful.

**Which links does Google index?**

```
<a href=”/good-link”>Will be crawled</a>
```

This is a regular a href link that will be crawled by Google.

```
<span onclick=”changePage(‘bad-link’)”>Not crawled</span>
```

Google will not crawl this link because it is not an anchor.

```
<a onclick=”changePage(‘bad-link’)”>Not crawled</a>
```

This link is in an anchor, but it does not use the href attribute. That’s why Google won’t crawl it.

```
<a href=”/good-link” onclick=”changePage(‘good-link’)”>Will be crawled</a>
```

This link will be crawled by Google because it is an anchor with a href attribute.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFwUbgvpdaQ)

Comment: Google can crawl dynamic links powered by JavaScript as long as they are written into the DOM when it loads.  You are correct that links written on click won't get crawled, but not all JavaScript powered links without static `href` backup are invisible to Googlebot these days.

Comment: No but the recommendations above come straight from Google, so while other implementations can and do work, it's no guaranteed.